# Raspbian Cronjob don't get triggered

Tags: python, cron, raspbian

I've created an cronjob by `crontab -e` with the following setup

```
15,45 0-23 * * * /usr/bin/python /home/wetter/scripts/capture_upload.py
```

Also i've changed the access permissions after read this in the internet by

```
chmod a+x capture_upload.py
```

But this Job don't get fired or there is a failure int he script, but if i run the script by `./capture_upload.py` it works like charm.

Can anybody help me solving this issue?

Comment: You should test cronjob by run command `/usr/bin/python /home/wetter/scripts/capture_upload.py`. If it works, I think that your cronjob will work too

Comment: Not a programming question. Nevertheless, the [`crontab` tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info) has a list of troubleshooting steps.

Comment: Don't know why to up vote this. It was an programming question. In the script, i used ".../" path, with can't resolved by the cronjob. Thanks @NguyenSyThanhSon for this hint.

Comment: I think that your question is good. I made a up vote.

Comment: Did you read the logs?

Comment: It's hard do debug without any details (cron jobs report errors either by sending you an e-mail, or to ``/var/log/syslog``).

Answer (score 1):

It was an programming question. In the script, i used ".../" path, with can't resolved by the cronjob. Thanks @NguyenSyThanhSon for this hint.